# WriteFile to serial port is working but the number of bytes written is zero

Tags: c++, winapi, virtual-serial-port

The issue:
my console application (Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2019) sends data via a USB virtual serial port.
All works fine until the WriteFile (see my code snipet) function reports zero bytes written even if the function does not fail (WriteFile returns TRUE).
The GetLastError() returns 1.
Please take in account that the COMM setup was properly executed (including read/write timeouts).

I understand that very similar cases have been raised in the past but really I have not found a clear explanation about the issue.

Any idea?

```
            if (!WriteFile(hPort, (LPCVOID)serout, 1 * sizeof(uint16_t), &byteswritten, NULL)) {
                printf("Error writing COMM port\n");
                return;
            }
            if (!byteswritten) {
                printf("Error bytes written COMM port %d", GetLastError()); 
            }
            FlushFileBuffers(hPort);

// COM SETUP
DCB dcb;
HANDLE hport;
std::string strport = "COM1";
TCHAR pcCommPort[16];
COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;
_tcscpy_s(pcCommPort, CA2T(strport.c_str()));

hPort = CreateFile(
    pcCommPort,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,      //  must be opened with exclusive-access
    NULL,   //  default security attributes
    OPEN_EXISTING, //  must use OPEN_EXISTING
    0,      //  not overlapped I/O
    NULL); //  hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices

if (!GetCommState(hPort, &dcb))
    printf("CreateFile failed with error %d.\n", GetLastError());

//  Initialize the DCB structure.
SecureZeroMemory(&dcb, sizeof(DCB));
dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);

dcb.BaudRate = 921600; //256000 Baud
dcb.ByteSize = 8; //8 data bits
dcb.Parity = NOPARITY; //no parity
dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT; //1 stop
if (!SetCommState(hPort, &dcb))
    printf("Fail setting serial port\n");

PrintCommState(dcb);

timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 1;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 10;
if (!SetCommTimeouts(hPort, &timeouts))
    printf("Fail setting tineout on serial port\n");// setting timeouts failed.

PurgeComm(hPort, PURGE_TXABORT | PURGE_RXABORT | PURGE_TXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR);
```

Comment: How did you call `CreateFile()`? Show us all your code. How you create the handle tells how it will be written to.

Comment: use `NtWriteFile` instead `WriteFile` - this api lost say `STATUS_TIMEOUT`. what value return `NtWriteFile` ?

Comment: Please check again my question. I added the code for COMM setup.

Comment: only `NtWriteFile` return correct status to you here

Comment: Your `SetCommState` call should be failing.  It's not legal to pass zero for all those other members.  Just one example: "The SetCommState function fails if the XonChar member of the DCB structure is equal to the XoffChar member." and in your code, both are zero.

Comment: Another example of why `SecureZeroMemory` will break everything: `fBinary` "If this member is TRUE, binary mode is enabled. Windows does not support nonbinary mode transfers, so this member must be TRUE."

Comment: 1. OK. Some setup values are not correct but please take in account that the SetCommState never fails in the current version; 2. In any case the WriteFile() behavior is sensless. It does not fail but transfers zero bytes.

Comment: @genoveseV Please show a complete code sample (including like how is `serout` defined?).  And call `GetLastError` immediately after the `WriteFile` fails like this: `if (!WriteFile(hPort, (LPCVOID)serout, 1 * sizeof(uint16_t), &byteswritten, NULL)) {
  printf("Error writing COMM port. Error code: %d\n", GetLastError());
 }`